# Apt preposition: 'into an organisation ??? which ... procedures were being practised'

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

Source: p 231 of 296, *Understanding Housing Policy*, by [Brian Lund](http://mmu.academia.edu/BrianLund)

> [1.] ... In addition, the CRE [Commission for Racial Equality] acquired the power to instigate a formal investigation into an organisation **of** which it had a reasonable belief that discriminatory procedures were being practised.  ...

Is the preposition **of** correct? I would've guessed **IN**, because this is how I parse the sentence:

> [2.] ... the CRE  acquired the power to instigate a formal investigation into an organisation **IN** which ... discriminatory procedures were being practised.  ...

Comment: It's awkward; this author does not betray much ability to use the language gracefully. What he probably has in mind is "The CRE believed **of** this organization that discretionary procedures were being practised there", but he got tripped up by his syntax. To my mind he should have written "an organisation **where** ...".

Comment: It would still be clumsy, but omitting the preposition entirely is better than the ugly **of** the author chose.  R Mac's rephrased answer is a better version still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the preposition "of" is not correct. In fact, the author should not have used a preposition there at all. The "reasonable belief" is a condition upon which the "power to instigate a formal investigation" depends, so the author should have used the word "if".

> [1.] ... In addition, the CRE [Commission for Racial Equality] acquired the power to instigate a formal investigation into an organisation **if** it had a reasonable belief that discriminatory procedures were being practised. ...